# How do I extract row/column elements from multiple tables with same schema in single query

Tags: mysql

My question is as follows: Given that I have three tables with exactly the same column names and exactly the same keys for the "name" column e.g.

```
Table r
name | A | B | C 
-----------------
elem1| 12| 41| 23
elem2|  5| 16| 94
elem3| 42| 93| 11


Table t
name | A | B | C
-----------------
elem1|  9|  8|  1
elem2|  3|  6|  5
elem3|  2|  1|  3


Table p
name | A | B | C
-----------------
elem1| 21| 14| 32
elem2|  5| 61| 49
elem3| 24| 36| 11
```

how can i merge all these tables into a set of rows as follows in a single query:

```
output
name | column | value
--------------------------
elem1|      A | "12,9,21"
elem1|      B | "41,8,14"
elem1|      C | "23,1,32"
elem2|      A | "5,3,5"
...  | ...    | ...
elem3|      C | "11,3,11"
```

or if it is simpler:

```
output
name |       A |       B |       C
------------------------------------
elem1|"12,9,21"|"41,8,14"|"23,1,32"
elem2|  "5,3,5"|"16,6,61"|"94,5,49"
elem3|"42,2,24"|"93,1,36"|"11,3,11"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the output in example2 like this:

```
SELECT t.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.A) as a, GROUP_CONCAT(t.B) as b, GROUP_CONCAT(t.C) as c
FROM (
    SELECT name,A,B,C FROM r
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name,A,B,C FROM t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name,A,B,C FROM p
) as t
GROUP BY t.name
```

and the one in example1 like this:

```
SELECT t.name,t.col,GROUP_CONCAT(t.val) as vals
FROM ( 
    SELECT name,A as val,'A' as col FROM r
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,B as val,'B' as col FROM r
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,C as val,'C' as col FROM r
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,A as val,'A' as col FROM t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,B as val,'B' as col FROM t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,C as val,'C' as col FROM t
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,A as val,'A' as col FROM p
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,B as val,'B' as col FROM p
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT name,C as val,'C' as col FROM p
) as t
GROUP BY t.name,t.col
```

Comment: Excellent... now is there a way to do it without knowing the explicit column names? i.e. when there are 100 columns to deal with? or should i just created a little script to create the full statement? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I don't think there is a way for arbitrary column names except a dynamically generated query.

Comment: I think that satisfies my requirements... thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be to use UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM A
     UNION
SELECT * FROM B
     UNION
SELECT * FROM C
```

or use a JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B
ON < A.name=B.name>;
```

[Read more about joins](http://www.tkhts.com/sql/mysql/mysql-join.jsp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: also check out UNION ALL depending on if you want to see duplicates or not. UNION filters out the duplicates, but this  incurs a performance penalty as it has to scan all results for duplicates

Comment: Unfortunately these solutions do not achieve either of the desired outputs. In the case of UNION, we simply stack the table entries on top of eachother but do not merge the rows that are the same based on the "name" column. 

In the outer join, we stack the tables side by side but do not merge the columns that are the same.

I have the feeling that there is one more step missing that can solve this problem... probably some kind of concatenation but I simply cant find a good reference.